# SSH Permission denied (publickey) while trying to connect to server using SSH

Tags: ssh

This is my first time trying to connect to a server using SSH. I have got details from my senior developer but when I try to connect then I get an error regarding Permission denied (publickey).

I tried to run the SSH command with debug parameters but it gives me a list of output that I am not able to understand much.

This is the command I am running

```
ssh -vvv [youruser]@[yourLinode]
```

And here is the output

```
OpenSSH_8.5p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/c/Users/pc8/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/c/Users/pc8/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "[yourLinode]" port 22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to [yourLinode] [54.213.195.223] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Platform.sh
debug1: compat_banner: no match: Platform.sh
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to [yourLinode]:22 as '[youruser]'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from [yourLinode]
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/known_hosts2:2
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from [yourLinode]
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-s
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:0k+lbQiTn4QgfmNupriYGozTdTOG9u6E5OxwhxWkHlk
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from [yourLinode]
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/known_hosts2:2
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from [yourLinode]
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '[yourLinode]' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/pc8/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
[youruser]@[yourLinode]: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I am not able to understand much by seeing these steps. I see 1 error that says file not found. Screenshot

[image]

Could some one please suggest if this is the error that I need to fix in order to connect to the server. And If yes then please let me know where I need to create this file (/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts).

Also If this is not the error then could someone help me understand the debugging steps and guide me what could be the issue.

I am using GitBash on Windows machine to connect to the server.

Please let me know if any more details is needed from my end.

Answer (score 3):

The line you highlighted looks like an error, but is normal. A few lines up, you can see that your client successfully found a file named known_hosts, and found the remote host key there. This file isn't needed to connect successfully, but the SSH client uses it to keep track of keys it already trusts, so you only have to check the key fingerprint once.

The real problem is evident at the end of the output you pasted: the server side only supports public key authentication, but the client doesn't find a private SSH key in any of the usual places, so it's unable to authenticate you to the server. You won't be able to connect until that's fixed.

The debug information you posted included this line:

```
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Platform.sh
```

That means you're trying to connect to an environment hosted by Platform.sh. You can find more information about how to make it work in the public documentation, on the page [Connect securely with SSH](https://docs.platform.sh/development/ssh.html). You can either install the Platform.sh CLI and let it configure your SSH client for you automatically, or you can [generate your own public/private keypair](https://docs.platform.sh/development/ssh/ssh-keys.html#1b-generate-new-keys), and then [add the public key to your Platform.sh account](https://docs.platform.sh/development/ssh/ssh-keys.html#2-add-an-ssh-key-to-your-platform-account). You can use [this guide on GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) to learn how to generate the key, it should work fine in Git Bash on Windows.

If you're going to be interacting with the project often, you'll find it more convenient to do that after installing the Platform.sh CLI, but if you prefer not to, you can generate and add the key without the CLI.

Finally, if you don't have a Platform.sh account, you can ask your developer for an invite, [using these instructions](https://docs.platform.sh/administration/users.html#add-a-user-to-a-project).

Answer (score 1):

You have to run `ssh-gen-key` on your local system and then copy the pulich key(s) it creates to your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the remote system. Public keys end in `*.pub`; don't copy the private keys that do not have that file name extension.

There is a program, `ssh-copy-id` which will do the copy provided you can log in using a password. Otherwise you'll have to do the copy some other way.

Comment: Close. First you have to run `ssh-keygen` (not ssh-gen-key) then execute the `ssh-copy-id youruser@yourLinode` As above, if you aren't authorized a password login for SSH initially, it can't update the authorized_keys files on the remote host, so as he stated you'll have to have an authorized user edit the youruser's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file to include the id_rsa.pub text.